# expected primary expression before '<' token

Tags: c++, this, cout

i m trying to run this piece of code i have written and i m getting this error.. DK why
i m working on windows 7 32 bit
my IDE is codeblocks and the compiler i m using is gcc
thanks for all the helpers

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int num[5];

    void operator[](int x){
        num[x]=3;
        cout << num[x] <<<endl;
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void func(){
     (*this)[2];
    }
};

int main(){
B b;
}
```

Comment: The error message will point out exactly where the problem is. Look closely. You have a typo.

Comment: Look at the code, closely. Where do you have `<`? It's only one line. You might want to improve the question as well - punctuation gives a better readability in your sentence, and if the compiler gives an error it is always nice to knwo i which line it gets the error.

Comment: Usually, compiler error messages will tell you the line number of an error. Use that information to check your code carefully, and you can solve these sort of problems quickly without having to go to SO.

Comment: Such localized questions should be answered in the comments itself. Strange to see 4 identical answers for *this* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout << num[x] <<<endl;
```

replace it with

```
cout << num[x] <<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this line
`cout << num[x] <<<endl;`

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << num[x] <<<endl;
```

You have 3 `<` here instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following character:

```
                 v
cout << num[x] <<<endl
                 ^
```